# how to break for loop in promise?

Tags: javascript, express, promise, sequelize.js

```
var ing_data = savedata.ingredients.split(',');    
for(var i =0; i<ing_data.length; i++){

      var d = {
            content_name: ing_data[i],
            dogFoodId: dogId
      }
      db.dog_ingredients.create(d).then(function(data){

      }, function(e){
            console.log(e);

            res.status(403).send('Error');
            //break for loop this point

      });
    }
```

how to break for loop in promise?

I'm using node express, sequelize module

Comment: Trying to mix sync and async code will only lead to tears.

Comment: Do you want to just end the loop? Or end the entire script because of error?

Comment: Well, in general you don't break the async operations loop unless you chain them. Yes, you can set a flag then query against this flag at each step - but the flag will only be checked in the next stack of command.

Comment: Your `then` callbacks will not be run until the loop is complete, so...they can't terminate the loop, that train has left the station.

Comment: By the time you want to *break the loop* - all of the promises could (and very likely will) have already been executed.

Comment: @Adam: But the `then` callbacks are *guaranteed* not to have been. (Er, by proper promises; if just thenables, then...)

Comment: Your for loop will already be run even before you have time to think about to break it or not. I think you better group all your promises in an array and `Promise.all()` them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop will be over before the first `then` callback is triggered; this is one of the guarantees of promises (assuming that `create` operation returns a proper promise, not just a thenable; or at least that the thenable it returns completes asynchronously).

You can use the `reduce` trick to loop through adding those ingredients **serially** (one at a time); a promise rejection along the way will skip the remaining ingredients:

```
savedata.ingredients.split(',').reduce(function(p, ing) {
    // Chain this ingredient on the end of the promise, return
    // the new promise `then` returns, which gets passed to the
    // next iteration
    return p.then(function() {
        var d = {
            content_name: ing,
            dogFoodId: dogId
        };
        // Return the promise from `create`
        return db.dog_ingredients.create(d);
    });
}, Promise.resolve()/* Seeds the loop above */)
.catch(function(e) {
    // We got a rejection, which bypasses any pending resolution
    // handlers we set up above; process the rejection.
    console.log(e);
    res.status(403).send('Error');
    return Promise.reject(e); // Only need to propgate the rejection like this
                              // this if something will use the return value of
                              // this overall structure
});
```

That looks massive, but that's mostly comments and the object initializer; we could also write it like this (assuming we didn't need to propagate the rejection):

```
savedata.ingredients.split(',').reduce(function(p, ing) {
    return p.then(function() {
        return db.dog_ingredients.create({ content_name: ing, dogFoodId: dogId });
    });
}, Promise.resolve())
.catch(function(e) {
    res.status(403).send('Error');
});
```

*(Or you can even get smaller, but for me debugging suffers — leave minifying to the minifier.)*

---

I assume you don't want to add the ingredients in parallel since you've indicated you want to stop on the "first" error. But if you did, the code would be simpler:

```
Promise.all(savedata.ingredients.split(',').map(function(ing) {
    return db.dog_ingredients.create({ content_name: ing, dogFoodId: dogId });
}).catch(function(e) {
    res.status(403).send('Error');
    return Promise.reject(e);
});
```

(Assumes we don't need to propagate the rejection.)

Again, though, that's parallel.

Comment: *(Doh! If you see `ing_data[i]` above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: +1, great answer. I wonder isn't this a use-case for imaginary `Promise.raceTillReject()` method, which completes either when all its param promises are resolved, or when any is rejected.

Comment: @raina77ow: That's what `Promise.all` does (https://jsfiddle.net/von1zduc/1/). The thing is, if you call `create` in advance to build the param promises, those `create` calls are already going, in parallel. Which is often what you want (see end of answer), but from the OP's desire to stop "early" I suspected they wanted to do things serially. If I found I needed to do the `reduce` above often, I'd definitely give myself a helper for it, though.